# Python Selenium_handle of pop-ups & timeout exception

Tags: python, selenium, popupwindow, timeoutexception

I am writing a code that will hopefully be able to click on a defined button on a pop-up window. The pop-up window appears only after having clicked somewhere else (this part is working).

here's the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button\[text()="OK"\]')))
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPATH, '//button\[text()="OK"\]'))
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.XPATH, '//button\[text()="OK"\]'))
driver.findElement(By.XPATH, '//button\[text()="OK"\]').click()
```

I am getting an error "TimeoutException". Anyone able to fix that?

thanks a lot

Comment: You are mixing here python, java... We need to see the page you working on and all your code to understand more. But seems the text is not exactly "OK" or maybe the element is not accessible.

Comment: thank you Prophet and sorry for my mistakes. I am still very limited with my python competences. Before that, there are only few rows that define the URL and the buttons that need to be clicked.

submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Open"]').click()

Comment: This is exactly what we are missing to make minimal debugging and try help you

Comment: Can you add `HTML` source for that element you want to click

Comment: ```TimeoutException``` meaning one of the 3 web elements you trying to locate fail and hit timeout error. You need to provide more details such as the URL or site that you are trying to access. Or at least some sample HTML source to determine if your locator is working properly.